# Resuming a previous scene from a current scene using the Unity3D

Tags: unity

I am building a first person shooter game using unity and I am facing the problem of resuming a scene from its current state. It would be easy to pause the scene by using the `Time.timeScale = 0.0;` within the scene itself. But I am loading a pause scene to ask whether the user wants to restart, resume or quit. But when I click on resume, it loads the scene I want, but it is totally fresh (i.e when the Ammo is supposed to be half full, it is full. Or the enemy has lost a part of his life, but then it starts with life completely full)

How do I resume the previous scene from where it left off using  `SceneManager`? This could have been somewhat easy by using the `Application.loadLevel()` and making sure that application does not destroy the previously loaded state.

Here is the script I made for the pause scene.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class pauseScript : MonoBehaviour {


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void exitPressed()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }

    public void restartPress() 
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("prototype1");
    }

    public void resumePress()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("prototype1");
    }
}
```

Here is the code snippet for calling the pause menu scene. and this is in another script.

```
SceneManager.LoadScene ("PauseMenu");
```

Is there anyway to save the current scene before calling the PauseMenu scene as shown in the above statement?
This may be a simple enough query to you but I am completely new to game development as a whole and I am using unity for the first time, so please go easy on me.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SceneManager](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) with `LoadSceneMode.Addtive`. By that you will be able to load another scene on your current scene.

And when you want to resume just unload Pause Scene using `UnloadScene`

```
//===============================================================================//
// Gameplay.cs
public bool _paused = false;

// Pausing Game
void PauseGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("YOUR_PAUSE_SCENE", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
}
//===============================================================================//


//===============================================================================//
// PauseMenu.cs

// Resuming Game
void ResumeGame()
{
    Gameplay gp = FindObjectOfType<Gameplay>();
    gp._paused = false;
    SceneManager.UnloadScene ("YOUR_PAUSE_SCENE");
}
//===============================================================================//
```

**Tip:** Remove Camera from your Pause Scene as LoadingScene in Additive mode will add all your game objects of pause scene in current scene.

Comment: Thanks for the advice mate, just one more thing, I put in a `bool paused` in my playerControl script to indicate whether the game has been paused or not. How do I set it to false upon the `SceneManager.UnloadScene ("YOUR_PAUSE_SCENE");` in my pauseScript script?

Comment: Several ways to do that.. Either you can get a public variable of `bool paused` in script where you are calling `UnloadScene ` by `SCRIPT_CONTAINING_PAUSED_VARIABLE obj = FindObjectOfType<SCRIPT_CONTAINING_PAUSED_VARIABLE>(); obj.paused = false;` before `UnloadScene`, or you can use delegates which'd be little more tricky. Let me know if first one doesn't work, then I'll update my answer with `Delegates` implementation.

Comment: check the edits by the way :)